# (VBA) when to use .cell(1,1) or .cell(1,1).value reference

Tags: vba

In my macros when I'm referencing to a value found in a cell, I've been inconsistently using either .cell(r,c) or .cell(r,c).value.

```
dim c as variant 
c = sheet1.cell(1,1) 'or sheet1.cell(1,1).value
```

Are both references correct or is there a preferred way?

Comment: They are both correct, many VBA programmers prefer `sheet1.cell(1,1).value`  since it is more explicit. In any event, I am voting to close this question as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @A.S.H I didn't have the strongest opinion about it being opinion-based. It is a bit borderline. Your answer is quite good.

Comment: @A.S.H "anonymous"??!?!  ("unanimous"?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.Value` is the *default property* of the range object. Therefore, when you assign something like this:

```
myVar = myRange
```

it is equivalent to `myVar = myRange.Value`, because you are assigning a variable  not an *Object*.

However, if you use `Set`, like this:

```
Set myObj = myRange
```

You would be assigning an object reference. The keyword `Set` tells VBA that you are assigning an object reference. The absence of `Set` makes VBA conclude that you implicitly want to get the `.value`, the *default property* of the range.

It is a good programming practice to use `.value` explicitly, for two reasons:

1- It makes code more readable, because the reader does not have to guess what is going on implicitly

2- With the advent of `VB.net`, the keyword `Set` has disappeared; the syntax for assigning an object or a normal variable becomes the same. For this reason, the *default property* idiom has disappeared with VB.net. Therefore, good practice is to use `.value` in VBA as well, because it makes an eventual porting of your code to VB.net much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you do Set c = sheet1.cells(1,1) you're referencing to the actual range?

Comment: @excelmonkey93, yes, surely. If you had "dimmed" c to be something else than `As Range` or `As Object` or `As Variant`, it naturally results in compiler error. The corner case is the `Variant` one, because here both assignments (to .value or to the object itself) are possible, and the `Set` keyword breaks the tie.

Comment: It is recommended to use `.Value2` though instead of `.Value`

Comment: @ja72 I agree, but that a different matter IMO, I didn't want to mix things up.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `.Value2` to get the value of a cell (or an array of vables from a range). If I don't use `.Value2` it means I want a reference to the `Range` objects and not the value. For example

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = Range("A1")

Dim x as Double, i as Integer
x = r.Offset(1,0).Value2

Dim vals() as Variant
vals = r.Offset(1,0).Resize(10,1).Value2

For i=1 to 10
    vals(i,1) = CDbl(i)/10
Next i

r.Offset(1,0).Resize(10,1).Value2 = vals
```

In addition I dont use the `Cell()` method because the location of cells may change in the future. I use *named ranges* with the `.Offset()` and `.Resize()` methods to set the range of cells I want read or write values to. So in the above code I would *never* use `Range("A1")` but something like `Range("my_table")` with a named range "my_table" defined on the top left cell of where I interact with.

---

There is a little known shortcut to get the value of a cell with the `[]` notation

```
Dim x as Double
x = [A2]
// This is the same as x = Range("A2").Value2
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. why do you use .value2 and not .value?

Comment: [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) _The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type._